# Thread Safety and Shared Resources

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been reading that code that is safe to call by multiple threads simultaneously is called thread safe. If a piece of code is thread safe, then it contains no race conditions. Race condition only occur when multiple threads update shared resources. Therefore it is important to know what resources Java threads share when executing.

I have a class as below;

```
public class ClassA {

JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

public void methodA(Map<?, ?> resultMap, String Url) {

    try {
        data.put("request_id", resultMap.get("request_id"));
        data.put("account", resultMap.get("account"));

        postToCallBackUrl.sendToCallBackUrl(data, Url, resultMap);

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        logger.error(e);
    }

}

public void methodB(Map<?, ?> resultMap, String Url) {

    try {
        data.put("request_id", resultMap.get("request_id"));
        data.put("name", resultMap.get("name"));

        postToCallBackUrl.sendToCallBackUrl(data, Url, resultMap);

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        logger.error(e);
    }

}
}
```

My question is on the usage of `JSONObject data = new JSONObject()`, is it thread safe as currently declared?

Or do I need to declare it in every method?

The data in all the methods is passed to another class `postToCallBackUrl` and a specific method `sendToCallBackUrl(data, Url, resultMap)`.

Anyone advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks wildly thread-unsafe. The [javadoc for `JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) explicitly states that the class is not thread safe. Since `data` can be accessed from the methods without any sort of synchronization, this is not a safe usage.

But the code doesn't even look safe for one thread to use, because state from one method invocation affects other method invocations.

Yes, create a new `JSONObject` as a local variable in the methods. It then becomes thread safe by confinement, and you retain no state between method invocations.